# Query regarding displaying a field in a table

Tags: java, mysql

I want to print the **DOB** field from a table with fields **ID,name,Designation,age,DOB**.
But I'm getting an exception instead. The piece of code i used is added below. Please help me !!

```
String bir="SELECT DOB from employee";
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(bir);
    while (res.next()) {
    String dob=res.getString(4);
    System.out.println(dob);
    }
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.getString(1)
```

You will use like that. Because you have selected one column only

Answer (score 0):

If you have error at finding the `columnIndex` then it's best to use `columnLabel` instead of `columnIndex`

```
String bir="SELECT DOB from employee";
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(bir);
    while (res.next()) {
    String dob=res.getString("DOB");  // remove the index and put the string DOB
    System.out.println(dob);
    }
```

Java Doc

```
String  getString(int columnIndex)
```

Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
[for more refrance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29)

```
String  getString(String columnLabel)
```

Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
[for more refrance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)